# How to add a tag to a timestamp td depending on time

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to add a tag to the td.timestamp class based on what time the news is generated.

I do not have the ability to add to the existing HTML, so must use jQuery and my experience is close to zero with that.

What i want to do is :

if td.timestamp has "minute,minutes,hour,hours or 1 day" then insert tag "new"

if td.timestamp has "days" then insert tag "recent"

so the html would now look like this

```
<td class="timestamp new">10 minutes</td>
<td class="timestamp new">5 hours</td>
<td class="timestamp recent">2 days</td>
```

here is how existing html is

```
<table class="report" align="center" cellspacing="1">
<caption><span>Latest Player News</span></caption>
<tbody>

<tr>
<th class="headline">Headline</th>
<th class="timestamp">Published</th>
</tr>

<tr class="oddtablerow">
<td class="headline">
<a href="http://football25.myfantasyleague.com/2014/view_news_article?L=77815&amp;ID=2014-02-21T21%3A47%3A00Rotoworld3291">Peyton Manning to have physical next wee...</a>
</td>
<td class="timestamp">10 minutes</td>
</tr>

<tr class="eventablerow">
<td class="headline">
<a href="http://football25.myfantasyleague.com/2014/view_news_article?L=77815&amp;ID=893058KFFL">Broncos | Peyton Manning will not need to restructure deal</a>
</td>
<td class="timestamp">1 hour</td>
</tr>

<tr class="eventablerow">
<td class="headline">
<a href="http://football25.myfantasyleague.com/2014/view_news_article?L=77815&amp;ID=893036KFFL">Broncos | Peyton Manning to be evaluated</a></td>
<td class="timestamp">5 hours</td>
</tr>

<tr class="oddtablerow">
<td class="headline">
<a href="http://football25.myfantasyleague.com/2014/view_news_article?L=77815&amp;ID=893036KFFL">Broncos | Peyton Manning to be evaluated</a></td>
<td class="timestamp">1 day</td>
</tr>

<tr class="eventablerow">
<td class="headline"><a href="http://football25.myfantasyleague.com/2014/view_news_article?L=77815&amp;ID=892708KFFL">Jaguars | Will not force picking a quarterback</a></td>
<td class="timestamp">4 days</td>
</tr>

<tr class="oddtablerow">
<td class="headline">
<a href="http://football25.myfantasyleague.com/2014/view_news_article?L=77815&amp;ID=893036KFFL">Broncos | Peyton Manning to be evaluated</a></td>
<td class="timestamp">20 days</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This jQuery example will look for the string "days" and insert "recent" if that string is found.  Any other type will get the class "new". [See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GBtLt/4/)

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
  $("td.timestamp").each(function( index ) {

    var timeStampType = $(this).text();

    if (timeStampType.toLowerCase().indexOf("days") >= 0)
    {
        $(this).addClass("recent");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("new");
    }
  });

});
```